# Polynom fit with big errors and wrong parameters

Tags: python, error, curve-fitting, polynomial

I have a question about polynomial fitting with python and I think its a more statistical question.

When I generate code for a polynomial function 3rd order with a not constant offset/error in the $y$-axis and then try to fit a polynom at it with `scipy.optimize` not only the errors are very big, but also the parameters are completely wrong. I even give the right parameter as starting point to `curve_fit`. Anyway, if I use a different Method (`numpy.polynomial` or Fityk) I get the same strange results.

Here is a minimalistic code-example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize, special
import random

x = np.arange(-8,8,1)
y = []
Parameter = [1,2.2,3,-1.54]
for i in range(len(x)):
    off = random.randrange(-50,50,1)/100 #plusminus 0.5
    z = x[i] + off
    tmp = Parameter[0]+Parameter[1]*z+Parameter[2]*z**2+Parameter[3]*z**3
    y.append(tmp)
    

def fit(x,a,b,c,d):
    return a+b*x+c*x**2+d*x**3
params, cov = optimize.curve_fit(fit,x,y,p0=[1,2.2,3,-1.54])
errors = np.sqrt(np.diag(cov))

print(params,errors)    

plt.plot(x,y,'rx',label="datapoints")
plt.plot(x,fit(x,*params),label="optimize-fit")
plt.plot(x,fit(x,*Parameter),linestyle=":",label="original")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The output is then for example
`[ 7.52024669  6.46958267  2.08168315 -1.59063913] [9.14611526 3.27003474 0.34030295 0.07992523]`  and the plot looks like this:

[image]

So the fit looks and follows the data points quite good, but the parameters $a$ and $b$ are very off, no matter how many data points there are.
Is there a way to make the fit better, or is this a statistical problem I can't quite grasp?

Maybe it's relevant to say that I have real measured data points which behave the same way, but are too odd to take in a minimalistic example. And sorry for the worse than average English.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Wolfmercury. [stats.SE] is a different than most sites; it's strictly Q&A. We don't think of threads as ongoing or evolving discussions. When a question has been answered, it remains for posterity, so others can discover it & learn. Please don't change your Q to update it to what you now need to know (ie, "We have already cleared..."). Instead, ask a new question. You can link to this, if that helps provide context. Since you're new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. In the interim, I have rolled this back to your original Q.

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't know that rule.

Comment: That's no problem, @Wolfmercury.

Answer (score 6):

You're adding noise to your `x` values, not your `y` values. Ordinary regression assumes that the only error is in measurement of `y`, not measurement of `x`.

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    off = random.randrange(-50,50,1)/100 #plusminus 0.5
    z = x[i] 
    tmp = Parameter[0]+Parameter[1]*z+Parameter[2]*z**2+Parameter[3]*z**3 + off
    y.append(tmp)
```

This gives estimated parameters of
`[ 1.07428852  2.20807026  2.99711762 -1.54046383]`, which is close to your real parameters. These aren't exact because of the random variation in `y`.

If you're trying to model random variation in the independent variable `x` instead of the more usual `y`, then you're looking for an error-in-variables model.

Comment: Yeah, I know that's not right, but this simulates my real data, which I can't influence, pretty good.

So does this implies that my measurements have a weird $x$-Delay?